# How to implement positive "lookbehind" of regular expressions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

**UPDATED QUESTION**

Suppose the string `"?foo=bar&nonfoo=bar&foo=bar"`, i need capture in this case:

- foo=bar
- foo=foo

I did with `Perl`, [see here](https://regex101.com/r/pD4iJ8/8).

But the Javascript doesn't support lookbehind, then the expression `(?<=)` (positive lookbehind) doesn't recognized.

I try too `(?:[?&])((foo\=[^&#]*)|(foo(?=[&#]))|(foo(?!.)))` (non capturing group syntax), but to execute the method `match` is returned:

- ?foo=bar
- &foo=foo

Comment: What exactly should be matched of this string `"foo?foo=bar&foo&foofoo"` ?

Comment: In this, only ```foo=bar``` and ```foo```. Don't ```foo?``` or ```&foofoo```.

Comment: well second `foo` in this comment ^ is that last `foo` in the string?

Comment: What do you think `[^$]` means, because I don't think it means what you think it means.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol sorry, typing error. Is ```[^&]```. Is not include ```&```.

Comment: @Rafael Laurindo, you say "In this, only foo=bar and foo", but in the question you say you "want include the last foo" as well.  Is that "last foo" the first "foo" or second "foo" of "foofoo"?  Also, would what you want change if you were given ""foo?foo=bar&foofoo&foo"?  Finally, what are you actually trying to do - just parse a URL query string?  (because simply splitting on "&" would be better)

Comment: @racraman forgiveness for not being clear. I want include the last ```foo``` if only the latter is equal to ```foo```, ```foofoo```, for example, must not match. I'm learning regular expressions.

Comment: @Shafizadeh i don't understand your question. Could be clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was in our face. Sorry for my late.

The final regular expression was thus:

```
\b(foo\b\=[^&#]*)
```

The especial character `\b` set a boundary word for matching, then, for example, it doesn't match "nonfoo=bar", but match "foo", "foo=bar" and doesn't include nothing before "foo" (works it as positive lookbehind), but if the word is after the URI Hash it is also matched (for now there is no way to solve this).

Comment: How about [`[?&](foo(?:=[^&#]+)?)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/pD4iJ8/10)?

Comment: Match ```?foo=bar```, but only not ```foo=bar```. It doesn't include ? or &.

Comment: `?foo=bar` is the whole match.  `foo=bar` is captured in group #1.

Comment: For make replace it? I will try. It's likely to work.

Comment: It works. With ```"if"``` statements inside a callback on ```.replace``` method for catch the separator(```?``` or ```&```), but it works so too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the example `"foo?foo=bar&foo&foofoo"` and `"foo?foo=bar&foo&foo"`

You could try the regex `(foo\=[^\&]*)|(foo(?=\&))|[^\w]foo(?!.)`

This will match `foo=bar` and `foo` from the first string.
and will match `foo=bar`, `foo` and `&foo` in the second string.

EDIT:

Using non-capturing groups to make up for the lack of negative lookbehind, you can filter out the last `&` using this regex:  `(foo\=[^\&]*)|(foo(?=\&))|(?:\&(foo(?!.)))`

[RegexDemo](https://regex101.com/r/eB6dU0/6)

Resulting in the capture groups for the matches over `"foo?foo=bar&foo&foo"`:

1) `foo=bar`

2) `foo`

3) `foo`

Comment: Sorry. It should not include ```&``` in any correspondence.

Comment: Could you include more example strings to be matched and what the desired output is?

Comment: I want besides [that](https://regex101.com/r/eB6dU0/3), that includes the last ```foo``` of the string ```"foo?foo=bar&foo&foo"```, but without the character ```&```. Understand?

Comment: This could easily be done using negative lookbehind `(?<!\&)`. Sadly, this is not possible in JavaScript. You may want to look into rewriting lookbehinds if you want a single entity regex to solve your needs.

Comment: You could try to intentionally match the leading `&` and then wrap it in a non-capturing group `?:`. The last part of the regex would then become `(?:\&)foo(?!.)`

Answer (score 1):

im not totally sure what your result should be ... but maybe this one could solve your problem:

```
(?!foo\?)(foo(\=[^\?^&]+)?)+
```

This will match:

- foo=bar
- foo
- foo **or** foofoo

Comment: It's almost that. Should not correspond to ```foofoo```.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think regex is the appropriate tool for this.

Instead, use `.split("?")` first to separate out the path and the query. Then take the query and `.split("&")` that. Now you have all the pieces you want.

You can loop through them to find the specific one you need, or go one step further and `.split("=")` them to separate key/value pairs.

All much easier than regex.

Comment: Part of learning regex, is learning when not to use it. It's like taking a sledgehammer to construct a ship in a bottle "because I'm studying sledgehammers".